# Add id to sencha nested list items

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha nested list that contains some elements from a store. I need to customize each element separately so I need to set a custom id to each. Can I achieve that in sencha touch 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to generate/populate the unique id in the store and then use the itemTpl to render the id out.

```
itemTpl: "<div id =\"{id}\" class=\"list-item-title\">{name}</div>"
```